# Hide mobile table on outlook

Tags: css, outlook, html-table, html-email

I create a newsletter, but I have a problem with a table on mobile.

I have a mobile table like this:

```
</table class="mobile_table" width="1" height="1">
    <tr>
        <td>
           <img src="mysource/test.jpg">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center">
           <img src="mysource/test2.jpg">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<style>
  .mobile_table{
        display: none;
        font-size: 0px;
        max-height: 0px;
        line-height: 0px;
        mso-hide: all;
        width: 0px;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
</style>
```

I try to hide my table on desktop version, it works on web version but on outlook the table is not hidden.

Can you help me on this subject ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Problem with Style in Outlook](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2462582/problem-with-style-in-outlook)

Comment: No duplicate, the problem is on the table no on the general layout...

Comment: Did you try inserting the styles inline? If so please update the question.

Comment: What version of Outlook are you testing this in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One work around I've found for this, is to use some email client targeting. Wrap the code below around your responsive only elements and it should be hidden in Outlook :) It's basically an if statement saying "If it's not MS Outlook, do this".

```
<!--[if !mso]><!---->
    <tr>
    <td class="show_only_mobile" style="width:0; max-height: 0; height:0; overflow:hidden; display:none;">
    <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="show_only_mobile">
        <tr>
            <td>
               <img src="mysource/test.jpg">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="center">
               <img src="mysource/test2.jpg">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </td>
    </tr>
<!--<![endif]-->
```

Then just reset all of the inline CSS in your responsive CSS.

```
.show_only_mobile {
    display : block !important;
    width : auto !important;
    max-height: inherit !important;
    overflow : visible !important;
    line-height: normal !important;
}
```

You just need to ensure that your code is valid both with, and without the code inside the mso tags.

Comment: It's work great, you know if exist a condition for gmail ?

Answer (score 0):

A handy tool to have bookmarked is Campaign Monitor's [CSS Support Guide for Email Clients](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/), which shows that some versions of Outlook do not support the CSS `display` property.

That is backed up by [this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338201.aspx) stating:

> The following is a list of all the top-level cascading style sheet properties that the Cascading Stylesheet Specification, Level 1 supports, but that Word 2007 does not support. Note that Word 2007 considers unsupported cascading style sheet properties to be unknown properties.
>
> - background-attachment
> - background-image
> - background-position
> - background-repeat
> - clear
> - ***display***
> - float
> - list-style-image
> - list-style-position
> - text-transform
> - word-spacing

Similarly, other "tricks" you normally might use to hide an element, such as changing its visibility and/or setting its dimensions to 0 and hiding its overflow are also not supported by those same versions of Outlook.